# AWS CLI: "cannot import name UnrewindableBodyError"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got below error when running 'aws' on a ec2 instance. Any clues what this problem is about?

```
>>aws configure

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 27, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/compat.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib3 import exceptions
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .request import make_headers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/request.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import UnrewindableBodyError
ImportError: cannot import name UnrewindableBodyError
```

Comment: "ec2 instance." - which one exactly? Ubunu, Amazon Linux, CentOS, which version?

Comment: if its amazon linux ami, aws cli is already installed, if its not you need to first install was cli to your instance then only you can use it

Comment: it's a RHEL. So this error means the aws cli is not installed? how can I verify if aws cli is installed or not?

Comment: you can try this command `aws --version` to check whether it is installed or not.

Comment: I have added the answer for your reference, do upvote it so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: This post may have the appropriate solution:
https://superuser.com/q/1618688/1206749

Answer (score -1):

In order to install aws cli on rhel 8 follow these steps

```
install python3-pip


pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

confirm it by this

```
aws --version
```

if you want to check out docs on [installation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install).

However my recommendation will be to **NOT** *store your aws credentials* ( programmatic key) within your instance because if by any chance your `instance is compromised so does your account too, or if instance is shared among other users, they will get access to your creds`.

if it was local or personal computer i would have recommended to go with `aws configure` command but since its not, the best practice will be to
**create IAM role,give permission according to your use case, and attach that role to your ec2 instance and then run aws cli commands.**

Comment: This doesn't address the problem at all. The OP already has awscli installed. The issue it that it is failing somewhere.

Comment: OP does not know whether aws cli is installed or not, please check comments

Comment: I conceed the point. I will remove my downvote if you want to edit your answer to accommodate. I don't want to penalise you for trying to answer a poorly formed question.